# Why was there no female minion?

Tags: despicable-me, despicable-me-2, minions

In the 3 minion movies i.e. Despicable Me 1, Despicable Me 2 and Minions, all the minions were male characters (including maid Phil :P). Why was not a single female minion character present?

Comment: Related (if not duplicate) question over on Science Fiction and Fantasy Stack Exchange: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/92209/are-there-any-female-minions

Comment: I swear that in the first film, Gru asks about one of the minion's spouse.

Comment: I too remember that

Comment: @Catija and Panther you both are making a pretty big assumption that the minion's spouse was a female minion (and it wasn't just a joke comment made by Gru). What's to say it wasn't married to a human, or an inanimate object (see minion hitting on a fire hydrant in the trailer to the new minion movie) ?

Comment: How can you tell that they are male?

Comment: @DA Agreed.  They could be gender neutral. They do seem to be eternal, after all, so they don't need reproductive parts! (And when shown without pants, they look like Ken dolls / mannequins. Except for their butts.)

Comment: But in Despicable Me 1, Gru said following statement to Kevin - "Looking good, Kevin! How is the family? Good?". What does this mean then?

Comment: @mailmehere: No gender does not mean no reproduction. See bacteria.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no female minions, apparently.

There's an article in The Wrap from July titled

**[‘Minions’ Creator Pierre Coffin on Why None of His Animated Little Yellow Helpers Are Female](http://www.thewrap.com/minions-creator-pierre-coffin-on-why-theres-no-female-characters-in-the-animated-hit/)**

In it, it is explained:

> For the French animator, who co-directed the new film with Kyle Balda, the masculine-only nature of the Minions owes to their all-around cloddishness. “Seeing how dumb and stupid they often are, I just couldn’t imagine Minions being girls,” he told TheWrap.

As to their ability to reproduce the article says:

> Coffin has said that the creatures cannot reproduce or divide themselves, leading to at least two competing theories.